# Unresolved dependencies Rollup does not merge dependencies

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I introduced 'core-js/modules/es.object.keys' in index.js, and Unresolved dependencies is prompted during the packaging process. The packaged file does not contain the keys method, but is introduced by require, define. If the browser does not support these two methods, then calling Object.keys will report an error.

So what should I do to get the polyfill code for Object.key in the result file.

My Index.js file

```js
import keys from 'core-js/modules/es.object.keys'

export { keys }
```

This is my rollup configuration file

```
{
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    file: 'lib/index.js',
    format: 'umd',
    name: 'MtUtils'
  },
  plugins: [resolve(), commonjs()]
}
```

Packaged result

```
;(function(global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined'
    ? factory(exports, require('core-js/modules/es.object.keys'))
    : typeof define === 'function' && define.amd
    ? define(['exports', 'core-js/modules/es.object.keys'], factory)
    : ((global = global || self),
      factory((global.MtUtils = {}), global.es_object_keys))
})(this, function(exports, es_object_keys) {
  'use strict'

  es_object_keys =
    es_object_keys && es_object_keys.hasOwnProperty('default')
      ? es_object_keys['default']
      : es_object_keys

  exports.keys = es_object_keys

  Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true })
})
```

I want the packaged file to contain the polyfill code for keys directly instead of being introduced via require or define . The final code here is the following code, so Object.keys is not available.

```
factory((global.MtUtils = {}), global.es_object_keys))
```